# How to configure bootpd server?

Tags: boot, configuration

How to configure bootpd server for a testing environment?

Comment: Can you add more info - what kind of testing environment? what do you want to do with the bootpd server? are you serving configs to infrastructure, platforms, other? etc. And why in askubuntu? This seems much more suited to superuser...

Comment: I actually found that I needed DHCP, and solved using GADMIN-DHCPD

Comment: This question appears to be abandonded, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag explaining that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found that I needed DHCP, and solved using GADMIN-DHCPD